# solr cache configuration for high performance queries

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

I have configured solr caches for my index in solrcloud 4.3.0.I have also configured autoCommit policy to 1h hard commit and opensearcher false. Though i am not reopening searcher,it seems that after every 1 hour my caches gets flushed and resets.As per my understanding only closing and opening the new searcher can cause caches to be flushed.But i don't understand why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to change `mergePolicy` settings? You can read about merging segments [here](http://juanggrande.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/merge-policy-internals/). I guess, your rare hard commits and the size of new segments requires Solr to merge segments, in this case the searcher should be reopened anyway.

Comment: I dont understand ! is there any connections between segment merging and solr caches ?

Comment: I suppose, that after merging segments the searcher should be reopened. But I may be wrong and the merged serments just placed near the old unmerged files, which wait to be deleted when you reload the core. I upvoted your question to be sure my hypothesis is correct.